# transform-style:preserve-3d not working in safari?

Tags: css, browser, safari

I try to take the Parallax Scrolling by transform-style: preserve-3d. It's good in android and chrome, but It is seem not work in Safari. I already use autoprefixer and add -webkit-. Why no effect?

```
 position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    perspective: 400px;
    -webkit-perspective: 400px;
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add below css in to you css code
`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; /* I added this */`

This will work on above version of safari of 3.1, 3.2.

Also please check this url:
https://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d

Answer (score 0):

I delete these code:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

It's can work on ios and safari. I don't know why...